# Iphone add image to project

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

i am new to iphone app development i was going through a tutorial and add images to project but unfortunately some time the images are available in dropdown for uiimageview and sometime they are not, can somebody help me why it is happening?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type the name of an image file into that dropdown field if dropdown doesn't show it.

Comment: I have type the name but it shows a question mark instead of image, the image is properly added to project.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your images are both present in the filesystem and also imported into the project.  If you still have trouble, restart IB.

Comment: The image is present both in file system as well in project, i can see the image in xcode window it shows the preview when i select it, i have restarted even my notebook but nothing is working for me.